# Why Cannot I see these controls in my XCode 4.2?

Tags: xcode, controls, xcode4.2

I downloaded a sample project from net when I opened it its object library has a lots of more controls than in my XCode , why cannot I see these controls in my XCode 4.2 IDE ?

[image: Missing Controls in my XCode 4.2 IDE ???]

How can I have these controls in my XCode 4.2 IDE ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set the deployment target as ios 5.0 and it's visible only in making of Empty Application. create one new empty application for universal and check your controles

Comment: if you want to use then use empty view controller of blue icon from library in which you can directly use those controller

Answer (score 3):

Those are the standard objects available for OS X (Cocoa) applications. My guess is that so far you’ve been using Xcode for iOS (Cocoa Touch) applications only.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on for what platform you are developing in an XCode-project. If you are working in a iOS XIB or Storyboard, there will be less conrols (only the iOS-supported controls)